# What is the proper usage of res.render() and res.redirect() in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having some trouble deciphering the ambiguity between

```
res.render('viewname', {msg: 'Message' })
```

and

```
res.redirect('route')
```

The redirect function does not let you pass a "message", but you may still want to, and the render function will render your view, but it will not change the URL of your web app and will not trigger the function which is required for your route.

The situation I am having is that I have an Invite form, which has an action that changes my URL, and triggers a function at that route which has a success and failure callback, and I would like to redirect users to the Dashboard with a message indicating success or failure.

Comment: from what you are describing you should have a POST and a GET defined.  in the POST request you want to redirect to your GET and in the GET you want to render.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

look at connect-flash to use rails style flashing of messages.

res.render() will render the view with data passed to it, res.redirect() will redirect a user to another page (at which point the request starts over)

Comment: Awesome - thank you. This is not the first time something has been removed from Express that was awesome - dunno why they keep taking stuff out, like the flash mem and EJS partials

Comment: i think if another libary provides feature, they remove it. I agree mostly with this logic, except it can be frustrating when they remove things you depend on. I use ejs-locals to get layouts/blocks/partials back.

Comment: this is my href

`<a class="nav-link" href="registration_requests.html">`
and this is my route

`router.get('/registration_requests.html',(req,res)=>{

    res.render('employees/registration_requests');

});`

but still 
Cannot GET /registration_requests.html